# How to use leading_zeros/trailing_zeros in platform independent way?

Tags: rust

I want find the first non-zero bit in the binary representation of a  `u32`. `leading_zeros`/`trailing_zeros` looks like what I want:

```
let x: u32 = 0b01000;
println!("{}", x.trailing_zeros());
```

This prints **3** as expected and described in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.trailing_zeros). What will happen on big-endian machines, will it be **3** or some other number?

The documentation says

> Returns the number of trailing zeros in the binary representation

is it related to machine binary representation (so the result of `trailing_zeros` depends on architecture) or base-2 numeral system (so result will be always **3**)?

Comment: This kind of methods have nothing to do with the platform AFAIK: they just take the binary representation of the number. Do you want to know the hardware representation of a number? That's usually pointless.

Comment: `0b01000` is `0b01000` in little endian, big endian, bi endian, space, other timeline, before the big bang. Yes the result will be always 3

Answer (score 10):

The type `u32` respresents binary numbers with 32 bits as an abstract concept. You can imagine them as abstract, mathematical numbers in the range from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1. The binary representation of these numbers is written in the usual convention of starting with the most significant bit (MSB) and ending with the least significant bit (LSB), and the `trailing_zeros()` method returns the number of trailing zeros in that representation.

Endianness only comes into play when serializing such an integer to bytes, e.g. for writing it to a bytes buffer, a file or the network. You are not doing any of this in your code, so it doesn't matter here.

As mentioned above, writing a number starting with the MSB is also just a convention, but this convention is pretty much universal today for numbers written in positional notation. For programming, this convention is only relevant when formatting a number for display, parsing a number from a string, and maybe for naming methods like `trailing_zeros()`. When storing an `u32` in a register, the bits don't have any defined order.